# Chef server for AWS INFRASTRUCTURE provisioning

Tags: chef-infra, provisioning, chef-solo, aws-opsworks, orchestration

I have recently started learning about Chef and it's capabilities for provisioning infrastructure. I want to push my cookbooks to AWS environment in order to provision various AWS components (without using OpsWorks Automate). My doubt is how to go about it?? Beacuse I'm confused in that in this case, what shall be the Chef server's address and how will it interact with AWS environment. Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either have to use Hosted Chef or run your own Chef Server. There are also workflows that don’t use Chef Server but they are not well documented and this not recommended for new users.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have started learning about Chef Zero and Chef Solo also. I hope these help me better understand the specifics of the environment setup.